# Pandas: Replacing part of string in column by position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As you can see, column B contains 4 characters.

```
A   B
aaaa    0007
baaa    0119
aaab    0232
abaa    0576
aaba    0924
```

I want to replace the **last two** characters for each line in column B with `00`, keep the first two characters, and save the result in column C. The expected result is below.

```
A   B   C
aaaa    0007    0000
baaa    0119    0100
aaab    0232    0200
abaa    0576    0500
aaba    0924    0900
```

I tried this:

`df['C'] = df['B'].replace(df['B'][2:3], "00")`

But the result is different because it changes line 2 to 3 in column B completely with `00`.

I use Python 3.

Comment: "But the result is different": Please explain.

Comment: Indexing starts with 0. It is doing what you asked it to do.

Comment: isn't it [2:4] instead of [2:3] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with:

1. extract the first 2 digits
2. transform them to string
3. append `00`

```py
df['C'] = df['B'].map(str).str[:2] + "00"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a bit of information about your answer; code-only answers are typically frowned upon because they are hard to understand and don't do anything to teach readers how or why they may serve as a viable answer to a question.